# SignalR Connections Won't Close? (IIS 10 + ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

We have a single-page web application running on 6 servers behind a load balancer. Recently, we have been experiencing occasional server crashes, and examining stack traces, it's possibly related to winWebSocketHandler+<>c__DisplayClass5_0+<b__0>d;0 [AWAIT#0].

When I looked at one of the servers current requests, I noticed a lot of these:
[image: IIS Image]

Is this the normal way that IIS represents WebSocket connections (State = EndRequest), or could they be hanging requests that are needlessly using up resources? If that's the case, how can we close those connections sooner?